# Display:none not working for textarea wrapped within <td> element

Tags: textarea, hide

I am trying to add or remove dynamic fields within table for use with jquery validation plugin.

Though I could not hide  element within table tried to wrap it using  as code below.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea style="display:none;">
            <textarea>Text for first Text Area</textarea>
            <textarea>Text for second Text Area</textarea>
            <textarea>Text for third Text Area</textarea>
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But my real problem is style="display:none" could able to hide first Text for first Text Area

All other textarea padding within it is visible.

Could someone help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I spend 2 days googling to find the answer but unfortunately could not find any solution. Finally I found the solution when I am teaching my nephew to write HTML code. Simply replaced < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;` then walla, it works.

Thanks everyone who tried to help me.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea style="display:none;">
            &lt;textarea&gt;Text for first Text Area&lt;/textarea&gt;
            &lt;textarea&gt;Text for second Text Area&lt;/textarea&gt;
            &lt;textarea&gt;Text for third Text Area&lt;/textarea&gt;
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```